# Model failed to simulate successfully_Version 8.8.6

Tags: anylogic

Original model was created in AnyLogic7. To open this model, I resave it in 8.8.6.
Although this model(8.8.6) can be successfully opened, it fails to run. It seems that there's an incompatibility between the new and old versions of Java.
I would like to inquire about how to modify the JavaScript.

```
for (Pedestrian thisPed : get_Main().pedestrian) {
    // for each pedestrian in model

    double pedX = thisPed.getX() - getX();
    double pedY = thisPed.getY() - getY();
    if (fieldOfView.contains(pedX, pedY)) {
        pedInDanger = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I modify get_Main().pedestrian to "main.pedstrain".
The code does not compile and give an error message "main cannot be resolved to a variable". I cannot figure out why the transition cannot recognise main.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your ped agent type is not embedded in Main as a population. Do that and it will work

Comment: Hi Ben,
thanks a lot for your response! I have another question, how do I get the Polygonal Node in the Project through java code?

Comment: pls always open new questions separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow